# Phonegap for android platform failed to generate .apk file of application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

i am using phonegap to create an application, to create my app i followed some procedure which present in [official phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) for windows OS. Every thing went smooth but when i tried to build the app for android through CLI it showed build successfully but not generated bin folder itself at `E:\Phone-Gap-App\appName\platforms\android` location so i did not get the .apk for my application

any help will be appreciated, Thanks .

Comment: Building using Gradle or Ant?

Comment: actually i installed ant tool and set the path of that and in documentation i red that while building app it will utilize ANT toll , pleas can u tell me the command to build using Gradle / ANT

Comment: in official phonegap Doc they return like  All android builds using any PhoneGap version above 4.0.0 will now use Gradle by default. http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/

Comment: Can you share your build output?

Comment: @MegaAppBear Pleas go to the following link for build file http://jmp.sh/b/rcRfJlNq90uMemzxqq7w

Answer (score 0):

Your Gradle build output will be in

`platforms\android\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: what ever u are telling is correct but cordova / phonegap is not creating .apk of application it is creating only android-debug.apk and android-debug-unaligned.apk. With out creating .apk with application name it's of no use

Comment: This is your apk. What do you expect it to be? Are you trying to create a release apk?

Comment: ya i want release apk

Comment: This wasn't your question. If you want to know how to build a release APK there's a lot of resources that can help you. Running "cordova build android" would create a debug APK which you can still run on a device, but you can't release.

Comment: sorry this is the first time i am working on phonegap and i thought release apk means the APK with application name , see after building the app i am going to import the whole project into the eclipse(i.e inside the platform folder) but while importing i am not getting the .apk file with application name (means any folder with the application name). i think if i get the file with the application name that will be proper build..??